# Finding the $x$ and $y$ values such that the partial derivatives are zero simultaneously

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y) = x^2 + 4xy + y^2 -4x + 16y + 3$

So, I proceeded with taking the partial derivatives:

$f(x,y)_x = 2x + 4y - 4$ and $f(x,y)_y = 4x + 2y + 16$

and

$f(x,y)_x = f(x,y)_y = 0$

$2x + 4y - 4 = 4x + 2y + 16$. This leads to a linear equation. However, they came out with a specific ordered pair, $(-6, 4)$

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your line is where the partial derivatives are equal *to each other*. They should also be equal to zero!

Comment: (Don't feel bad, I stared at it for a long time without seeing it :P )

Comment: Well, I figured since that both the partial derivatives were equal to zero, then they must equal each other. Why can't I just simply set them equal to zero?

Comment: You can. But the point is that in your derivation you haven't used the fact that they're equal to zero. If you now use either zero-condition, you'll find that only one point on your line satisfies it.

Comment: Oh, I see! So, the way I solved it gives me more solutions than I want. It includes the point when they are both zero, but it also includes when they are both, say, 2 (I didn't actually verify if they actually equal each other at that value). Is that correct to think?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. (Well, I'm slightly confused by what you mean by "if they actually equal each other", but you seem to have got the main idea).

Comment: What I meant is that I didn't check if each partial derivative is equal to 2 at the same x and y values.

Answer (score 4):

Each equation is equal each other, yes, because *each equation is equal to zero*!. So we have a simple homogeneous system of two linear equations in two unknowns:

$$2x + 4y - 4 = 0 \tag{1}$$ 
$$4x + 2y + 16 = 0.\tag{2}$$

Multiply equation $(1)$ by $-2$ and add to equation $(2)$:

$$-6y + 24 = 0 \implies y = 4$$

Substitute $y$ into the first equation:

$$2x + 4(4) -4 = 0 \iff 2x = -12 \iff x = -6$$

$$\text{Solution}:\quad (-6, 4)$$

Answer (score 3):

$$2x+4y-4=0\implies x=2-2y\tag{1}$$

and $$4x+2y+16=0\implies 8-8y+2y+16=0 \tag{putting x from (1)}$$ $$\implies y=4$$ Putting $y=4$ in $(1)$ gives $x=-6$