# Finding the x and y values such that the partial derivatives are zero simultaneously (part two)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

$f(x,y)= \ln(x^2 + y^2 +1)$

The partial derivatives of $f(x,y)$ being:

$f_x(x,y) = \frac{2x}{x^2+y^2+1}$ and $f_y(x,y)=\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2+1}$

Setting each partial derivative equal to zero, adding the two linear equations two, and solving for $y$, I get:

$y = - x$

In this problem [Finding the $x$ and $y$ values such that the partial derivatives are zero simultaneously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326417/finding-the-x-and-y-values-such-that-the-partial-derivatives-are-zero-simult), there was only one ordered pair. In the problem before us, I solved it the same way I did in the problem given in the link Does the solution above imply that there are an infinite amount of $(x,y)$ pairs, such that there partial derivatives are zero? I ask, because this particular problem is an even number, and the answer key provides no answers for such questions.

Comment: No, you get $x = y = 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: Since the denominators of these partial derivatives are never zero, then the partial derivatives are equal to zero *precisely* when their numerators are.

Comment: Yes, that is what I did. Then I had simultaneous equations, $2y = 0$ and $2x = 0$. When I added the two equations together, I got $2x +2y = 0 \implies y = -x$.

Comment: As in the other problem, you've added your equations together unnecessarily. You should **only** add two equations together if it eliminates variables. In this case, your variables are all but solved for. $2y=0$ implies $y=0$ and $2x=0$ implies $x=0$. Thus, $(0,0)$ is the solution point.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you, Cameron!

Comment: P.S.: If you *do* add equations together to eliminate variables, don't forget to back-substitute at the end, so you can solve for all of the variables!